# GRUB Dual Boot On 2 HDD's

Tags: grub2, grubrescue

I have 2 HDD's(One is new, other one is old). I Windows 7 installed in one of them (new one) and I decided installing Xubuntu to another one(old one). So, I did it. However, It moved to boot manager to the old one. When I remove the old one from my PC, It doesn't boot. It opens a grub rescue terminal. How can I fix this?

Comment: Your narrative is little confusing. You have installed windows-7 on new HDD and Xubuntu on older HDD. Could you login on both windows-7 and Xubuntu successfully after installation? Did you try it? What is the meaning of `I remove the old one from my PC`? Please clarify.

Comment: Yes, I can login on both windows-7 and Xubuntu right now. My concern is when my old drive will be dead, I won't be able to use my PC. To sure that, I removed the old drive(Xubuntu) from the PC and tried to boot my PC but it said "error: unknown file system. Entering rescue mode. grub rescue>". What I want is configure my PC in order to work without old drive in case my old drive might be corrupted.

Comment: If your Old Drive (ubuntu installation) is dead, you can still access windows-7  because it is installed on another drive. What you should do is to go to BIOS screen and make sure that windows-7 bootloader must be set up to top priority. Of course, when your old HDD (ubuntu installation) goes down , GRUB setup too goes down. So you get  `grub rescue` message. Please tell me can you access BIOS setup screen by pressing `del` key? Please make sure that Windows bootloader is set to  top priority and try to boot again on windows-7.

Comment: I accessed BIOS and changed the boot priority from my old-drive to my new-drive. Now, it stucks at "Verifying DMI pool data..." when i try to boot my pc.

Comment: Please edit your question and post the `complete` output displayed when you try to boot from your PC.

Comment: Please attach your old HDD. Make a normal login to windows-7 and then update current Firmware BIOS Version. Refer [How to Check Your Current BIOS Version and upadate it](https://www.howtogeek.com/196916/how-to-check-your-bios-version-and-update-it/).  After updating BIOS firmware, you may detach old HDD and then try to boot into windows-7 and see you are successful!